# Python requests-html - How to return links with css selector?

Tags: python-requests

How can I get only the links using requests-html?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

r = session.get("https://www.jobs.ch/en/stellenangebote/?term=")
joblist = r.html.find(".x--job-link.t--job-link", first=False)

for job in joblist:
    print(job)
```

Expected result (shortened):

```
/en/vacancies/detail/8252670/?source=vacancy_search_promo
/en/vacancies/detail/8252610/?source=vacancy_search_promo
```

Current result (shortened):

```
<Element 'a' class=('x--job-link', 't--job-link') href='/en/vacancies/detail/8252670/?source=vacancy_search_promo'>
<Element 'a' class=('x--job-link', 't--job-link') href='/en/vacancies/detail/8252610/?source=vacancy_search_promo'>
```

Tried without success:

```
joblist = r.html.find(".x--job-link.t--job-link", first=False).links
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
for job in joblist:
    print(job.links)
```